# How to put data on separate lines in python

Tags: python, lines

This is my code:

```
 if mode == "1" and classname == "1":
            f = sorted(open("alphabetical test.txt").readlines())
             print(f)
```

Every time it prints the data from the file it prints it like this:

```
['A, 9, 6, 2\n', 'K, 10, 1, 2\n', 'M, 5, 3, 7\n', 'P, 3, 5, 9\n']
```

How can i get rid of the '\n' and how do i put them on separate lines?

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean with "put them on separate lines? You have generated a list `f` which contains the sorted rows from your input; what you now do with that list is up to you :)
also, please fix your indentation, it's all wrong: `print(f)` can't be indented by one space below `f =....`.

Comment: When the data is printed i want them on seperate lines, one under the other.

Comment: why do you want to remove the newline if you want the output on separate lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your

```
print(f)
```

To

```
print(''.join(f))
```

The string `''.join()` method takes a list (or other iterable) of strings, and joins them into one big string. You can use any separator you like between the substrings, eg `'---'.join(f)` will put `---` between each of the substrings.

The `\n` in your list of strings is the escape sequence for the newline character. So when you print that big string made by joining your list of strings then each of the original strings from the list will be printed on a separate line.

Answer (score 2):

Just call .strip() on each line from the file:

```
f = sorted([line.strip() for line in open("alphabetical test.txt").readlines()])
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove whitespace and newlines from a string, you can use [str.strip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) or their variants
[str.lstrip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.lstrip) and [str.rstrip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.rstrip), respectively. As for a pretty printer, there's [pprint](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html).

An example:

```
if mode == "1" and classname == "1":
    # use context manager to open (and close) file
    with open("alphabetical test.txt") as handle:
        # iterate over each sorted line in the file
        for line in sorted(handle):
            # print the line, but remove any whitespace before
            print(line.rstrip())
```

Comment: `rstrip` would probably be better